# Share (through share menu) directly to own email address

Tags: contacts, share-menu

I often send over images etc to my own email for forwarding or printing or what ever.

Problem is I have many contacts, and I have to type quite a bit to find my own email address.

I would really like to have a share-menu option that says "Share to [specific email address]".

Is there any application that provides such option??

Comment: You could rename the contact for yourself to "zz Me" or something, so that you can get it quickly by typing "zz".

Comment: @aioobe: Do you really have that many contacts with names similar to yours? If I start typing my name or e-mail address in the field my name is isolated within about three characters. As suggested in other comments, a good workaround may be to make the contact entry for yourself have a unique set of characters.

Comment: Al Everett, yes. I have a fairly common name, and I have to punch in at least 5-6 chars to get my name in the list.

Comment: your email address is that common too? because if you start typing that, you will show up that way.

Comment: You'd have to develop a (small) app to handle the "share to my email address" unless one already exists.  I'd append a symbol - or similar to bump your name to the top of the list.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a solution that will work if you are sharing images from the browser.  This won't work in the gallery though.  Unfortunately I'm not aware of any custom share apps that add to the Gallery's share menu.

**Install [Bookmarklet Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kurtchen.android.bookmarklet.free)** (it allows you to add services to the "Share" menu, including custom ones).

To make a custom "Mail to yourself" bookmarklet just open the app and create a custom bookmarklet that has the following for the Starting URL:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=YOUR@EMAIL.COM&su=SUBJECT
```

Replace YOUR@EMAIL.COM with the email you want to default send to and replace SUBJECT with the subject.  Leave the rest of the fields alone.

Now in the browser if you are looking at an image you can long click it and choose share and choose your custom bookmarklet.

Comment: This doesn't work on DroidX Froyo stock. Opens up gmail web site but NOT the email with the link

Answer (score 2):

The [Autoshare](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dngames.autoshare) app in the Android Market can do this.

- Once this app is set up, **it is 100% non-interactive** — you do NOT have to edit the email or click a "Send" button. Everything gets filled out and sent in the background. This is a major benefit!
- However, the app requires you to set up an email server/password/userid to do that. With Gmail it was a breeze to set up. I don't think this app uses the Gmmail app — it connects straight to Google's SMTP server.

Comment: Why not provide a link to the Market page or website for the app? Telling someone to "go search the Market" is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @eldarerathis - there was a URL in the post - somehow the formatting made it invisible! Whoever downvoted - please upvote

Comment: As a note - I have tried both this method and "Bookmarklet Free" from the highest voted answer. This worked beautifully, **with zero interaction from me**, whereas the other one didn't work at all