# desktop shortcut that takes a photo and emails it to a fixed address

Tags: email, photos, home-screen-shortcuts

I am registered with a website that can archive scans of receipts.  One way to upload the receipt image is to email it to an email address that's tied to my account.

To expedite the process, I want a shortcut on my Android desktop that, when pressed, starts the camera, lets me take & review the photo, and then emails the photo to a fixed email address.  I've found lots of apps that take photos and automatically upload them to your favorite photo sharing site, but I haven't run across any that will send them to a pre-configured address.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com)?

Comment: There are a bunch of apps on the playstore for services like that (e.g. [Expensify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.me.mobiexpensifyg)). Did you check if your website has such an app attached?

Comment: @Izzy My website does not.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A partial solution: If you could add the specific email address to your share menu you could just use whatever camera app you wanted. Check this question and its answers: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/share-through-share-menu-directly-to-own-email-address

Comment: Using tasker your could create a task that takes a photo and then sends an email with the photo attached.